# Starting and Terminating child of simple_one_for_one supervisor

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I have a simple application `target_interceptor` that upon receiving register and unregister messages, starts or terminates workers under `simple_one_for_one` `rpc_server_supervisor`.

The code of supervisor `rpc_server_supervisor`:

```
init([]) ->
    MaxRestart = 5,
    MaxTime = 3600,
    {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, MaxRestart, MaxTime},
            [{rbmq_rpc_server, 
                {rbmq_rpc_server, start_link, []},
                temporary,
                10000,
                worker,
                [rbmq_rpc_server]}]}}.
```

register message of `target_interceptor`:

```
handle_cast({register, Args}, S = #state{channel = Channel, supervisor=Sup, refs=R, qs_link = QSLinks}) ->
    {Connection, QueueName, Node} = Args,   
    {Ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_child(Sup, [Connection, QueueName, Node]),
    Ref = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
{noreply, S#state{refs=gb_sets:add(Ref,R), qs_link=orddict:append(binary_to_list(QueueName),Pid,QSLinks)}};
```

unregister message of `target_interceptor`:

```
handle_cast({unregister,{QueueName}}, S = #state{supervisor = Sup, qs_link = QSLinks}) ->
    Pid = orddict:fetch(QueueName,QSLinks) 
    case supervisor:terminate_child(Sup,Pid) of
         ok -> Success = true;
         Error -> io:format("Error ~p~n",[Error]),
                  Success = false
    end,
{noreply, S#state{qs_link=orddict:erase(QueueName,QSLinks)}}
```

my version of Erlang is : R15B01

The first problem is when handling register action the tuple {OK, Pid} = {error, <0.57.0>}; even though it indicates that something went wrong, the gen_server rbmq_rpc_server on Pid 57 is working correctly and responding to messages. Why is the return value of start_child function error? What went wrong?

The second problem is when handling unregister action, where supervisor:terminate_child(Sup,Pid) returns {error,simple_one_for_one) even though I reference Pid not ChildID. Why is it behaving like this and how could I dynamically and individually terminate children of my supervisor?

EDIT:
Both `target_interceptor` and `rpc_server_supervisor` are supervised by `rbmq_sup_sup` supervisor :

```
init({Nodeid, Node}) ->
    MaxRestart = 1,
    MaxTime = 3600,
    {ok, {{rest_for_one, MaxRestart, MaxTime},
            [{server,
                {target_interceptor, start_link, [target, self(), {Nodeid, Node}]},
                permanent,
                5000,
                worker,
                [target_interceptor]}]}}.
```

EDIT:
rpc_server_supervisor is called in target_interceptor init() function (Sup here is rbmq_sup_sup supervisor):

```
handle_info({start_worker_supervisor, Sup}, S = #state{}) ->
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_child(Sup, ?SPEC),
    link(Pid),
    {noreply, S#state{sup=Pid}};

-define(SPEC,
        {rpc_server_sup,
            {rpc_server_sup, start_link, []},
            temporary,
            10000,
            supervisor,
            [rpc_server_sup]}).
```

Answer (score 1):

I will add to this as I get time.

A first point is that `{Ok,Pid}` matches any tuple even `{error,Error}` so calling the *variable* `Ok` might not be the best choice.

A quick question: in `handle_cast({register,Args}, ...` you do `binary_to_list(QueueName)` for the key but in `handle_cast({unregister,{QueueName}}, ...` you just use `QueueName` for the key. Why? Why do you keep a list of pids for each QueueName as unregister seems to clear them all? This will also mean that when you do `Pid = orddict:fetch(QueueName,QSLinks)` Pid will be a list of pids not one.

In `rbmq_sup_sup` you only start `target_interceptor`.

Are the `rbmq_rpc_server` processes registered?

**EDIT:**

I think the reason for error when doing `unregister` is that you have saved the pid with `orddict:append/3` which saves the value in a *list*, even the first time, while you are getting the value with `orddict:fetch/2` which returns the whole list in this case. So `Pid` is a list. You then try kill the child with `Pid` which is a list of the pid not the pid which is what `supervisor:terminate_child/2` is complaining about.

If you only have one pid per `QueueName` then you should do `orddict:store(binary_to_list(QueueName), Pid, QSLinks)` instead. Then `orddict:fetch/2` will return the pid.

P.S. The idea behind `orddict:append/3` is that you can add more values to the same key and it keeps a list of all the values.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks but this does not cause my problems 1.) {Ok,Pid} tuple is there only for demonstration 2.) in register cast, QueueName has form of binary and in unregister - List format, I should unite it for readability 3.) I list Pids to be able to unregister the right process when message arrives. (un)register msg comes through rbmq channel to target_interceptor, handle_info(#'basic.deliver',#'amqp_msg') is used and casts (un)register messages with appropriate QueueNames

Comment: 4.) There is only one process for each QueueName and therefore each QueueName is unique and can be terminated through Pid reference; 5.) rbmq_rpc_server is started in target_interceptor init function so it has a ref on supervisor and target_interceptor can start/terminate children of supervisor when requested.